# Spring MVC: how to get a handler method for a request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement some logic depending on annotation present on method with Spring `@RequestMapping` annotation.

So I have a `HttpServletRequest` instance in my method and I want to ask spring "give me a method, which will be invoked to handle this request", so I can use reflection API to ask if my annotation is present or not, so I can alter the processing.

Is there any easy way to get this information from Spring MVC?

Comment: What you want to do is terrible.  That stated, instead of calling the method yourself, build a request dispatcher in your servlet and dispatch the request to the desired url.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way. Instead, you should use AOP, so that all calls to methods annotated with your annotation go through an Aspect that would do the processing. Here's an example intercepting all the calls to methods annotated with `@Authenticated`, and throwing an exeption if the current user is not authenticated: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/10ba6b0b6023e0d8ac228d2450d96193

Comment: _"I have a HttpServletRequest instance in my method"_ Which method? It sounds like you are in method X and want to know if method X has annotation Y.

Comment: The purpose is simple. Custom CSRF protection annotation. Spring security request matcher gives you only the HttpRequest object, not the target, so you need to look it up somehow... Which can be done with RequestMappingHandlerMapping (but here comes the second gotcha, as Spring security is bound strictly to ROOT context - so RequestMappingHandlerMapping is pretty useless with child webcontext... So thats why this question)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suppose you have a handler method like:

```
@SomeAnnotation
@RequestMapping(...)
public Something doHandle(...) { ... }
```

And you want to add some pre-processing logic for all handler methods that are annotated with `@SomeAnnotation`. Instead of your proposed approach, you can implement the `HandlerInterceptor` and put your pre-processing logic into the `preHandle` method:

```
public class SomeLogicInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                             HttpServletResponse response, 
                             Object handler) throws Exception {

        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            SomeAnnotation someAnnotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
            if (someAnnotation != null) {
                // Put your logic here
            }
        }

        return true; // return false if you want to abort the execution chain
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to register your interceptor in your web configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new SomeLogicInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to inject the handler object into a @ModelAttribute method? I didn't want to create an interceptor for this.

Comment: @deantoni AFAIK no there isn't

Comment: I agree with this solution, but you do not have to use getMethodAnnotation and check null, you can use `hasMethodAnnotation(Class<A> annotationType)`, which return straight boolean

Comment: I tried to do rate limiting in an Aspect, but it caused a lot of trouble because you're outside the spring error boundary so any exception thrown by the aspect wouldn't trigger the @ExceptionHandler methods but instead redirect to the error page. With the interceptor example, it worked right away. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Helped by @ali-dehgani's answer, I have a more flexible implementation that doesn't need to register an interceptor. You do need to pass the request object that is bound to be mapped to that method.

```java
private boolean isHandlerMethodAnnotated(HttpServletRequest request ) {
        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());
        Map<String, HandlerMapping> handlerMappingMap = BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(webApplicationContext, HandlerMapping.class, true, false);
        try {
            HandlerMapping handlerMapping = handlerMappingMap.get(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class.getName());
            HandlerExecutionChain handlerExecutionChain = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
            Object handler = handlerExecutionChain.getHandler();
            if(handler instanceof HandlerMethod){
                Annotation methodAnnotation = ((HandlerMethod) handler).getMethodAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
                return methodAnnotation!=null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```