# In Spring MVC, how to retrieve the @RequestMapping name's value?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/cPathA", name = "cNameA")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/pathA", name = "nameA")
    public Void pathA() {
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "pathB", name = "nameB")
    public Void pathB() {
    }

}
```

How should I retrieve the `name` 「nameA or nameB」of a method? Preferably do this inside the `doFilterInternal` method.

I tried to check inside the `HttpServeletRequest` but there does not seem to be any part where I can retrieve the name. Closest that I can use is `HttpServletRequest`'s `request.getServletPath()` which returns `/api/v1/cPathA/pathA` but I would like to get the actual name.

The `JwtAuthenticationFilter`:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JWTServiceImpl jwtServiceImpl;
    private final UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    private final GetCookieByName getCookieByName;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String jwtToken;
        final String refreshToken;
        final String userEmail;

        String name = request.getServerName(); # returns localhost
        String path = request.getServletPath(); # returns /api/v1/cPathA/pathA
```

Also: preferably  when I access pathA method, I will get both the `cNameA` and `nameA` might be as a chain `cNameA.nameA` or an array. But I can be satisfied on at least getting the `nameA`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be obtained through interceptors, create an interceptor bean, and inherit HandlerInterceptorAdapter, rewrite preHandle () method, in this method can obtain the information of the target processor, including the name.

```
@Configuration
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
        method.getAnnotation(PostMapping.class).name();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample code for this?

Comment: I added to the original answer,Filter can not meet your needs, because filter is called by the web container, has not been executed into the Spring framework, so can not get Controller information.

Comment: Tried this method but what happens is this is processed **after** the doFilterChain. I want to do this inside doFilterChain method so that I can do some conditions based on which request is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` to scan them.
Try this

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(RestController.class));
    for (BeanDefinition beanDefinition : scanner.findCandidateComponents("your.controller.package.path")) {
      log.info(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
      try {
        Method[] methods = Class.forName(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName()).getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
          if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PostMapping.class)) {
            PostMapping annotation = method.getAnnotation(PostMapping.class);
            log.info(annotation.name());
            log.info(Arrays.toString(annotation.path()));
          }
          if (method.isAnnotationPresent(GetMapping.class)) {
            GetMapping annotation = method.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class);
            log.info(annotation.name());
            log.info(Arrays.toString(annotation.path()));
          }
        }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
```

Don't forget  replace `your.controller.package.path` by your controller package.

Comment: This may work but I can see that you will need to add the controller here. I  was hoping to do this during a REQUEST.

Comment: Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102569/spring-mvc-how-to-get-a-handler-method-for-a-request). It's similar to your question